# I am using Ubuntu 14.04 install ionic framework but i cant create sample project in my pc and cannot create todo directory i fallow below commands

Tags: ionic-framework

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs 
$ sudo apt-get install npm
$ sudo npm install -g cordova
$ sudo npm install -g ionic
```

successfully done above commands but then I type

```
$ ionic start todo blank
```

but cannot notice anything after that I type

```
$ cd todo && ls
```

command, I notice that

```
bash: cd: todo: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You may want to give my tutorial and script a shot.  I am an Ubuntu developer myself.  https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

What you would need to check is that your *ionic start* command runs successfully. Most probably you are in a directory, where you don't have the permission to create the directory etc.